# Unexpected end of input pass by value function?

Tags: javascript, php, input

I want an image, when clicked, to pass a string that I have pulled from a database onto a Javascript function.

However I get this error when clicking on an image:

> Unexpected end of input

My code:

```
<script>
            var vidembed;

            function changevid(strcode){

                vidembed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + strcode;
                document.getElementById("vidFrame").src=vidembed
            }
</script>



<embed id="vidFrame" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>


<?php

$sql = "SELECT URL FROM tablename";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $strcode = $row['URL'];
        echo "<div class='cont1'><div class='cont'><img onclick='changevid('$strcode')' class='vid' src='https://img.youtube.com/vi/" . $row["URL"] . "/mqdefault.jpg' /></div></div>";

    }
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You should use different quotes for inside and outside of the `changevid` function, escaping the double ones because the php string is in double quotes:

```
onclick=\"changevid('$strcode')\"
```

[See working version](https://ideone.com/Tj5egB).

Comment: I tried that, but i get a php error, because of the echo using ""

Comment: @M.Collins did you try with the `\"`? (I updated the answer)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be through the use of PHP's [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
echo <<<HTML
<div class="cont1">
  <div class="cont">
    <img onclick="changevid('$strcode')" class="vid" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{$row['URL']}/mqdefault.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
HTML;
```